# Getting blank rows in combo box - why and how to remove?

Tags: c#

I'm populating a combobox as follows

```
SQLCommand.CommandText = @"Select * from templates where ObjectiveID = " + ObjectiveID + "";
SQLConn.Open();
adapter.SelectCommand = SQLCommand;
adapter.Fill(ds);
adapter.Dispose();
SQLConn.Close();
this.cbo_Template.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
this.cbo_Template.ValueMember = "TemplateID";
this.cbo_Template.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

For some reason, my combobox has 8 blank rows in it, then the single value that is returned by the SQL. Why? And how can I make it just have the value returned from SQL?

nb, I'm aware that my SQL isn't parameterised. I'm working on it :)

Comment: are you sure that `Tables[0]` is the table created?  if there were other tables in the ds, that new one wont be `[0]`

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to use a DataSet - a DataTable will do; that way you don't need to use `.Tables[0]`. And the `.Fill` command will take care of the `.Open` and `.Close` for you, so you don't need those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your dataset tables before filling it

```
ds.Tables.clear();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Moreover, why there is a extra concatenation in sql query. Remove it

```
SQLCommand.CommandText = string.format("Select * from templates where ObjectiveID = {0}", ObjectiveID);
```

Comment: As per my post, I'm aware that the SQL is not parameterised correctly. It's just how I am working through it right now. However, your main point about `ds.Tables.Clear()` solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @GavinP, Welcome, consider using local instance of `dataset` rather a global one to avoid this issues.